# Remote PowerShell, which machine is making the incoming connection?

Tags: windows, powershell, remote

I'm trying to identify the connecting machine within a remote PowerShell session.

The reason is so a script can behave differently depending on which machine is connecting.

Get-PSSession doesn't give enough information. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think this is possible so I might want to close this question...